Many-to-many with composite key in JPA Spring Java
I have this two entities:
@Entity
public class A implements Serializable{
 
 @Id
 @Column(name = "idA")
 String idA;

 @Column(name = "idB")
 String idB;


//Getters, setters, equals, hash...

}


@Entity
@IdClass(BPK.class)
public class B implements Serializable{
 
 @Id
 @Column(name = "idB")
 String idB;

 @Id
 @Column(name = "idB2")
 String idB2;

 @Id
 @Column(name = "idB3")
 String idB3;

 @Id
 @Column(name = "idB4")
 String idB4;


//Getters, setters, equals, hash...

}

Im trying to implement a ManyToMany relationship between these two entities in many ways, and I've gotten an error with every thing've tried.
I would like to do something like this:
@Entity
public class A implements Serializable{
 
 @Id
 @Column(name = "idA")
 String idA;

 @Column(name = "idB")
 String idB;

 @ManyToMany
 JoinColumn(name = "idB", referencedColumn = "idB")
 List<B> b;


//Getters, setters, equals, hash...

}

But this way of implementing this relationship only ends up in retrieving a null whenever I go for a getB(). I've tried many things and none of them have worked so far. How would be the correct and working form of implementing this many-to-many relationship?

When establishing a many-to-many relationship with a composite key in JPA, you typically use the join table approach, as the mapped-by approach doesn't directly support composite keys. Here's how you can implement a many-to-many relationship with a composite key using a join table:
Join Table Approach with Composite Key:
You create an entity for the join table and use composite primary keys to represent the relationship between the entities.
The composite primary key consists of foreign key columns referencing the primary keys of the associated entities.
Example:
@Entity
public class StudentCourse {
    @EmbeddedId
    private StudentCourseId id;

    // Additional attributes if needed

    @ManyToOne
    @MapsId("studentId")
    private Student student;

    @ManyToOne
    @MapsId("courseId")
    private Course course;

    // Getters and setters
}

@Embeddable
public class StudentCourseId implements Serializable {
    private Long studentId;
    private Long courseId;

    // Getters and setters, equals(), hashCode(), and constructor
}
@Entity
public class Student {
    @Id
    private Long id;
    // Other attributes

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "student")
    private List<StudentCourse> studentCourses;
}

@Entity
public class Course {
    @Id
    private Long id;
    // Other attributes

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "course")
    private List<StudentCourse> studentCourses;
}

In this setup, StudentCourse serves as the join table entity with a composite primary key (StudentCourseId). The @EmbeddedId annotation is used to indicate that the primary key of StudentCourse is a composite key. @MapsId annotation is used to map the composite primary key columns to the corresponding foreign key columns in the Student and Course entities.
This approach allows you to manage a many-to-many relationship with a composite key effectively.
